# Is a GIST index on a geometry point useful to speed up a spatial query?

Tags: postgresql, postgis, geometry, gist-index

I have multiple tables with point geometries and a GiST index eating many gigabits of space.

From what I understand about GiST indexes on polygons or polylines, it will store the bounding box and compute a first calculation on the bounding box instead of the full geometry resulting in faster processing.

But what about point geometry? Will it do anything more than ordering the points spatially?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case the original question and the bounty are due to some misconception about what the index does exactly and how, [here](https://www.crunchydata.com/blog/indexes-selectivity-and-statistics) is [Paul Ramsey](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-3.3/postgis_introduction.html#psc) with some pictures. And here's [PostgreSQL doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes.html).

---

> In what way would a GiST index on a Geometry(Point) (not talking about
> MultiPoint) column be useful?

In a dramatic way. It's not that it somehow makes points get processed faster, it's that it lets you skip the ones you don't need to process at all and get to the ones you need, more quickly.

> Would it be useful in a spatial processing (example: ST_DWithin) with a (Multi)Polygon column indexed with a GiST index?

Yes, that too. Consider this [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/vzhZKfva):

```sql
create table test_points(id smallserial primary key, pt geometry(Point));
create table test_points2(id smallserial primary key, pt geometry(Point));
create table test_polygons(id smallserial primary key, poly geometry(Polygon));

--2k random points, each
insert into test_points (pt) 
select st_makepoint(random()*1e3,random()*1e3)
from generate_series(1,2e3,1);

insert into test_points2 (pt) 
select st_makepoint(random()*1e3,random()*1e3)
from generate_series(1,2e3,1);

--1k random polygons
insert into test_polygons (poly) 
select st_convexhull(
        st_collect(
            ARRAY[  st_makepoint(random()*1e3,random()*1e3),
                    st_makepoint(random()*1e3,random()*1e3),
                    st_makepoint(random()*1e3,random()*1e3)
                 ]
        )
       ) 
from generate_series(1,1e3,1);
```

Point-point `ST_DWithin` with a radius of 30 and point-polygon `ST_Intersects()`, both without an index on either side:

```sql
explain analyze verbose --point-point
select p1.id, count(p2.id)
from test_points p1 left join test_points2 p2 on st_dwithin(p1.pt,p2.pt,30)
group by 1;
--Execution Time: 10117.017 ms

explain analyze verbose --point-polygon
select test_points.id, test_polygons.id
from test_points right join test_polygons on st_intersects(pt,poly);
--Execution Time: 4771.741 ms
```

With a GiST index on `Geometry(Point)` column, one's about 50x faster, the other about 2x:

```sql
create index test_points_pt_gix on test_points using gist(pt) 
   with (fillfactor=100);--fancy
cluster verbose test_points using test_points_pt_gix;--even fancier

explain analyze verbose --point-point
select p1.id, count(p2.id)
from test_points p1 right join test_points2 p2 on st_dwithin(p1.pt,p2.pt,30)
group by 1;
--Execution Time: 230.952 ms

explain analyze verbose --point-polygon
select test_points.id, test_polygons.id
from test_points right join test_polygons on st_intersects(pt,poly);
--Execution Time: 2611.132 ms
```

Comment: Tks (+1). You answered 'Yes, that too' to my second question, but in the examples you provided you did not include a GiST index in the polygon table, didn't you? If it had one, would the GiST index in the point table make a difference?

Comment: Depends on row counts and function in use. In my test the planner will always do a seq scan on the smaller table table and an index scan on the larger, in search for matches. See this ([demo1](https://dbfiddle.uk/8pJJtgRi)): 5k points vs 3k polygons = seq scan on polygons+index scan on points. When the scales tip the other way ([demo2](https://dbfiddle.uk/7oVTudH-)), it seq scans points, index scans polygons; in that scenario, it doesn't matter whether you have an index on points ([demo3](https://dbfiddle.uk/zSMsO7gf)). Still, better to have it and not need it than to need it and not have it.

Answer (score 3):

All PostGIS geometry values store the bounding box in their header; this does not need an index.

---

A GiST index on a geometry column allows for searching exact or nearby positions without having to do a full table scan, just like a 'normal' B-tree index allows searching for plain values without having to do a full table scan.

Many (but not all) PostGIS functions can use a GiST indexes. This is noted in the reference; for example, [ST_DWithin](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html):

> This function call includes a bounding box comparison that makes use of any indexes that are available on the geometries.

There is no such note for [ST_Distance](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Distance.html), so you should never do a distance search with `ST_Distance(geo1, geo2) < 42`. (If you ever need to search for the N nearest objects, note that the [<->](https://postgis.net/docs/geometry_distance_knn.html) operator is almost the same as ST_Distance, but does support an index when used for ORDER BY.)

---

Geometries need a different index type because they are two-dimensional values. A simple sorting (as with ORDER BY) would not be very useful; the internal R-tree used by the GiST index also has two dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

A GiST index on points can be very useful. It will speed up queries with `st_contains`, `st_overlaps` and similar functions in the `WHERE` condition, where one of the arguments is the indexed column.